# Javascript to Jquery, add text in input onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change this javascript code to JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addTextTag(text){
    document.getElementById('text_tag_input').value += text;
   }        
</script>
```

When a user click the link text automaticaly is added in input.

This is the HTML:

```
<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />

<div class="tags_select">
    <a href="#" onClick="addTextTag('text1, '); return false">text1</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="addTextTag('text2, '); return false">text2</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="addTextTag('text3, '); return false">text3</a>
</div>
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/j8qGT/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.tags_select a').click(function() {
            var value = $(this).text();
            var input = $('#text_tag_input');
            input.val(input.val() + value + ', ');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and your markup:

```
<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />

<div class="tags_select">
    <a href="#">text1</a>
    <a href="#">text2</a>
    <a href="#">text3</a>
</div>
```

and here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kn3Qu/2/).

Comment: That replaces the text in the text input, rather than appending the new text. May also be a good idea to use `.text()` rather than `.html()` just in case there are additional HTML tags inside the anchor.

Answer (score 3):

Without inline javascript, completely jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/j8qGT/3/

JavaScript:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#text_tag_input').val($('#text_tag_input').val()+$(this).html()+', ');
});
​
```

HTML:

```
<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />

<div class="tags_select">
    <a href="#">text1</a>
    <a href="#">text2</a>
    <a href="#">text3</a>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

Some notes on the steps:

- select already the input where to set the value so you avoid the need to re-query for it all the time: `var $tagsInput = $('#text_tag_input');`. The hash tag selector if the ID selector in jQuery, replaces `document.getElementById`
- bind a click event with .click() for links within element with class "tags_select": `$('.tags_select a').click(...);``
- To append the value, instead of *struggling* with jquery methods to get and set the value of the input, get the native DOM element with `[0]` on `$tagsInput` and use the `+=` notation of the property `value`.

Here's the code:

```
// select already you input element for re-use
var $tagsInput = $('#text_tag_input');

// bind a click event to links within ".tags-select" element
$('.tags_select a').click(function() {
    // append link text to the input field value
    $tagsInput[0].value += $(this).text();
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vMWxs/)**

Further reading:

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [Bind a click event with .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)