# onclick fill input box with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have pretty much copied and pasted from [this Stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452296/javascript-to-jquery-add-text-in-input-onclick), and it doesn't seem to want to work on my page. I also tried creating a blank PHP page to try it on, and it still doesn't work.

Also the jQuery library that I included in the header was one off Google's library, and also jQuery's official one: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.

It has to be something with the encoding or something because the code works fine in my browser on JSFiddle also:
http://jsfiddle.net/kn3Qu/

Here is the code I'm using personally:

```
<input id="dam" type="text" />

<div id="dam_return">
    <a href="#">DLH Victoria</a>
    <a href="#">DLH Sam</a>
    <a href="#">Studly</a>
</div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
$('#dam_return a').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    var input = $('#dam');
    input.val(value);
    return false;
});
```

If anyone could help me out that would be awesome!

EDIT: I'm thinking my problem is because of a SQL query that happens everytime a key is pressed on the "dam" input.

Here is the EXACT SQL query that happens:

```
<div id="dam_return_search"><a href="#">Maybe this one works? (but no, it doesn't)</a><br />
<?php

$connect = // blahblahaa

if (isset($_GET['dam_text'])) {
    getSuggest($text);
}

function getSuggest($text) {

    $dam = $_GET['dam_text'];

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT `name` FROM `alpacas1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$dam%'";

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<a href=#>'.$row['name'].'</a><br />';
    }

}

?>
</div>
```

Here is the DAM input box and code associated with it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function suggest1() {
    var dam_text = document.getElementById('dam').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('dam_return').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var target = 'dam_search.php?dam_text=' + dam_text;
    xmlhttp.open('GET', target, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dam_return_search a").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).html();
        var input = $('#dam');
        input.val(value);
    });
});
</script>


<tr>
  <td id="label">Dam:</td> 
  <td id="option">
    <input type="text" name="dam" id="dam" value="<?php echo "$dam"; ?>" onkeyup="suggest1();"><br />
    <div id="dam_return"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? it seems to be working

Comment: Make sure that you include only one jQuery import in your application

Comment: If you read it you'll see that it works on JSFiddle and everything, it doesn't work on my page. @Alex Well neither work standalone.

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you posted. Probably you have some errors that occur earlier in execution of your script. Check for errors and warnings in your browser. Also make sure that there is only one div with id = "dam_return", because it is a common mistake to give the same id to multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having Javascript in the initial file change the input box "dam" I changed it so that the dam_search.php file changed it "onclick".

Here is the code I had:

```
<div id="dam_return_search"><a href="#">Maybe this one works? (but no, it doesn't)</a><br />
<?php

$connect = // blahblahaa

if (isset($_GET['dam_text'])) {
    getSuggest($text);
}

function getSuggest($text) {

    $dam = $_GET['dam_text'];

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT `name` FROM `alpacas1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$dam%'";

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<a href=#>'.$row['name'].'</a><br />';
    }

}

?>
</div>
```

Here is what I changed it to:

```
<?php

$connect = // blahblahaa

if (isset($_GET['dam_text'])) {
    getSuggest($text);
}

function getSuggest($text) {

    $dam = $_GET['dam_text'];

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT `name` FROM `alpacas1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$dam%'";

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<a href=# onclick="document.getElementById(\'dam\').value=\''.$row['name'].'\';">'.$row['name'].'</a><br />';
    }

}

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the DOM of the page to fully load before initiating a .click() event listener. You can do that using [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyzyl/9stgu/) of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dam_return a").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).html();
        var input = $('#dam');
        input.val(value);
    });
});
</script>

<input id="dam" type="text" />

<div id="dam_return">
    <a href="#" class="test">DLH Victoria</a>
    <a href="#" class="test">DLH Sam</a>
    <a href="#" class="test">Studly</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man, added this, didn't change a thing, still doesn't work. Also you forgot to close one of the functions in that code snippet.

Comment: Edit: it worked testing on a blank page, but it does not work in my application. I think it is because the variables in the div "dam_return" are variables from a MySQL database and are queried everytime a key is pressed in the "dam" input box.

Comment: So change the name of the variable.

Comment: No, I think it isn't working because it's getting the text from another PHP page. Not because variables are messed up. (I have tried changing variables many times).

Answer (score 1):

well i think that you should consider using this code, frankly i think that you should not be using the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) jquery method to grab text, you should use the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method, i tried this code offline and online, it works

and please use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to stop an event, rather than return false

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tags_select a').click(function(evt) {
        var value = $(this).text();
        var input = $('#text_tag_input');
        input.val(input.val() + value);
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

also you can read about the difference between return false and preventDefault() [here](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)